# How to insert multiple records at the same time?

Tags: sql, powerschool

I have a problem with insert statement when I want to do insert on more than one record. My current code works fine if I have one record for insert but if I have more than one I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unexpected exception occurred: javax.persistence.PersistenceException

root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Here is my code that I use to build my dynamic table and execute insert statement:

```
while(time1 < time2){
    var timeFormat = hourStart+ ':' +minStart+ ' - ' +addHour+ ':' +addMin;

    myVar+= "<tr><th>Slot</th><td><input type='hidden' id='event_id' name='CF-[:0.U_EVENTS.U_EVENT_SLOTS:-1]EVENT_ID' value='"+eventID+"'/><input type='hidden' id='slot' name='CF-[:0.U_EVENTS.U_EVENT_SLOTS:-1]SLOT_LABEL' value='"+ timeFormat +"' />"+timeFormat+"</td></tr>";
}
```

First time when I got this error I was thinking that maybe something is wrong with the values that I'm trying to insert but once I realize that single record got inserted with no problem, then I was start looking in my insert statement. I'm not sure why this code works for single record but not for multiple. Is something wrong with my tags? Or I have to reference my tables in different order? If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. My values that I'm inserting look like this:

```
EVENT_ID      SLOT_LABEL

1545          7:00 AM - 7:30 AM
```

Here is whole error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unexpected exception occurred: javax.persistence.PersistenceException

type Exception report

message Unexpected exception occurred: javax.persistence.PersistenceException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

runtime.support.InternalException: Unexpected exception occurred: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor$ActionRunner.run(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:44)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemHandler.runInHandler(LegacySystemHandler.java:34)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor.intercept(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:27)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.intercept(PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.java:21)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HttpHeadInterceptor.intercept(HttpHeadInterceptor.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PSSiteMeshFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilterGuarded(LTKFilter.java:350)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilter(LTKFilter.java:164)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:87)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2188)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2192)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3386)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3315)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2999)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2979)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    com.pearson.powerschool.springutil.PerfCaptureProfiler.profile(PerfCaptureProfiler.java:36)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.syncChildTableValues(Unknown Source)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX$RecordChangeList.submitAll(DoAMRX.java:806)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitEachChanges(DoAMRX.java:1748)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitAllChanges(DoAMRX.java:1723)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1446)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1407)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.HandleActions.HandleActions(HandleActions.java:119)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.PPAdminPage.PPAdminPage(PPAdminPage.java:123)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.AdminInterceptor.intercept(AdminInterceptor.java:106)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PageHitInterceptor.intercept(PageHitInterceptor.java:59)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HandleHitInterceptor.intercept(HandleHitInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor$ActionRunner.run(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:42)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemHandler.runInHandler(LegacySystemHandler.java:34)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor.intercept(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:27)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.intercept(PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.java:21)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HttpHeadInterceptor.intercept(HttpHeadInterceptor.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PSSiteMeshFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilterGuarded(LTKFilter.java:350)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilter(LTKFilter.java:164)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
    org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:371)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:78)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2188)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2192)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3386)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3315)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2999)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2979)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    com.pearson.powerschool.springutil.PerfCaptureProfiler.profile(PerfCaptureProfiler.java:36)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.syncChildTableValues(Unknown Source)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX$RecordChangeList.submitAll(DoAMRX.java:806)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitEachChanges(DoAMRX.java:1748)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitAllChanges(DoAMRX.java:1723)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1446)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1407)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.HandleActions.HandleActions(HandleActions.java:119)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.PPAdminPage.PPAdminPage(PPAdminPage.java:123)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.AdminInterceptor.intercept(AdminInterceptor.java:106)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PageHitInterceptor.intercept(PageHitInterceptor.java:59)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HandleHitInterceptor.intercept(HandleHitInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor$ActionRunner.run(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:42)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemHandler.runInHandler(LegacySystemHandler.java:34)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor.intercept(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:27)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.intercept(PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.java:21)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HttpHeadInterceptor.intercept(HttpHeadInterceptor.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PSSiteMeshFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilterGuarded(LTKFilter.java:350)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilter(LTKFilter.java:164)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00957: duplicate column name

    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    util.jdbcwrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:59)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
    org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:371)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:78)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2188)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.dao.ExtendedFieldsDao.doSqlUpdate(ExtendedFieldsDao.java:2192)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3386)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.doInsert(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:3315)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2999)
    com.pearson.powerschool.tools.extendedtables.sdkimpl.ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.syncChildTableValues(ExtendedFieldServiceImpl.java:2979)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    com.pearson.powerschool.springutil.PerfCaptureProfiler.profile(PerfCaptureProfiler.java:36)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.syncChildTableValues(Unknown Source)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX$RecordChangeList.submitAll(DoAMRX.java:806)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitEachChanges(DoAMRX.java:1748)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.submitAllChanges(DoAMRX.java:1723)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1446)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.DoAMRX.DoAMRX(DoAMRX.java:1407)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.HandleActions.HandleActions(HandleActions.java:119)
    com.pearson.powerschool.app.PPAdminPage.PPAdminPage(PPAdminPage.java:123)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.AdminInterceptor.intercept(AdminInterceptor.java:106)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PageHitInterceptor.intercept(PageHitInterceptor.java:59)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HandleHitInterceptor.intercept(HandleHitInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor$ActionRunner.run(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:42)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemHandler.runInHandler(LegacySystemHandler.java:34)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.LegacySystemInterceptor.intercept(LegacySystemInterceptor.java:27)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.intercept(PowerSchoolEnabledInterceptor.java:21)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.interceptor.HttpHeadInterceptor.intercept(HttpHeadInterceptor.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PSSiteMeshFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilterGuarded(LTKFilter.java:350)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.LTKFilter.doFilter(LTKFilter.java:164)
    com.pearson.powerschool.web.filter.PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(PSSAMLDelegatingFilterProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

Comment: Where is your insert statement?

Comment: name='CF-[:0.U_EVENTS.U_EVENT_SLOTS:-1]EVENT_ID' this is insert statement for powerschool. Like I mentioned above this works for single record but does not work for multiple records. Error that I posted above is when I tried to insert more than one time slot.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a primary key (or other unique constraint) on `EVENT_ID`? Looks like you're trying to insert with the same ID, this would throw an error.

Comment: I tried to get rid of EVENT_ID and just insert multiple SLOT_LABEL at once but still I got the same error. Also I do not have primary key on EVENT_ID column.

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL generated? I don't think there are a lot of people familiar with powerschool (8 people following the tag, 18 questions on the tag)

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your `myvar` concatenations you get duplicate column names. But I can't tell you where without the actual SQL which is generated

Comment: Powerschool does insert trough name Tag and I do not where I can find generated SQL.

Comment: You are using Oracle right? Doesn't it have a function to display the last executed query? (More familiar with sql server myself)

Comment: You could also try to evaluate the final `myVar` content.

Comment: What you mean by evaluate final myvar? Also this is what I found insert into U_EVENT_SLOTS (ID, SLOT_LABEL,WHENCREATED,WHOCREATED) values (:"SYS_B_0", :1 ,:2 ,:3 )

Comment: To me that insert statement doesn't look right. What are those colons doing there? What are your datatypes? By evaluate I meant debug the content when it's exited the while loop. I don't think I can help you find a solution beyond this, I'm afraid.

Comment: I checked myVar after I executed while loop but I can not see any problem in there. I think something must be with powerschool code. Thanks for your time and help @HoneyBadger.